# Why am I getting Index out of bounds?

Tags: java

My code is giving this error:

> Index out of bounds

Why is causing this error?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Integer, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    System.out.println("First input number of your years then name:");
    Scanner sken = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (sken.hasNext() && !sken.equals("exit")) {

        String[] line = sken.nextLine().split(",");
        String name = line[1];
        int howOld = Integer.parseInt(line[0]);
        hashMap.put(howOld, name);
    }
    System.out.println("Input Complete!");

    System.out.println("HeshMap input:");
    System.out.println(hashMap + "\n");  // <-- this line


    Map<Integer, String> treeMap = new TreeMap<>(hashMap);
    System.out.println("Sorted by years:");
    System.out.println(treeMap);

}
```

Also, I'm sure that the line I marked with comment won't print properly, how is the proper way to print a HashMap?

Comment: What's with `!sken.equals("exit")`? You can't compare a `Scanner` to a `String` - it will always be true.

Comment: ops , you are right , gotta fix that first.

Comment: Although in this case doesn't seem necessary, when you get an exception like this, you should add the Call Stack to your post. Help us help you. And you should open a separate question regarding how to print the HashMap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reason of Exception**

Following line cause of occurrences `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1` because you are trying to `sken.nextLine().split(",");` I the string entered does not contain `,` in it you cannot get `line[1];`

```
String[] line = sken.nextLine().split(",");
```

**How about refactoring code**

Your input should contain `,` character as per your logic, and exit will be work like this.

```
while(sken.hasNext())
    {

        String thisLine = sken.nextLine();
        if(thisLine.equals("exit")){
            break;
        }
        String[] line =thisLine.split(",");
        String name= line[1];
        int howOld= Integer.parseInt(line[0]);
        hashMap.put(howOld, name); 
    }
```

**More**

May be helpful for you ;)

```
while(true)
        {
            System.out.println("Please Enter Age:");
            int howOld = sken.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Please Enter Name:");
            String name = sken.next();
            String thisLine = sken.nextLine();
            hashMap.put(howOld, name); 

            System.out.println("Do you want the results (Y/N)?");
            String more= sken.next();
            if(more.equals("N") || more.equals("n")){
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer , but what I need to do then ? I mean , you got it , I want to split line somehow in integer and string and then write it in hashmap

Comment: I think your sorted map will works. Why wouldn't you ask age than name one by one. It reduces chance of errors

Comment: that's not bad idea at all , but I like it the way it is now :D . It worked now . On "exit" command it prints out all stuff , thanks

Comment: Right, I you want it in the same way, Try to give sample input as well. Cause i read your while loop line by line to see what should be your valid input

Answer (score 0):

```
String name= line[1];
```

This above line is the Culprit , you are accessing index `1` without checking that even if it exist or not .

If your input string does not contain any comma as delimiter `,` then you'll surely get this Exception , So it's better to check before accessing

```
if(line.length==1){ // then Access index 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Always have a try catch handler check for handling exceptions such as this.

```
try{
 String[] line = sken.nextLine().split(",");
 String name= line[1];
 int howOld= Integer.parseInt(line[0]);
 hashMap.put(howOld, name); 
} catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException iobe) {
   // do something here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Sarz made a whole new while loop and it's doing fine :)